# Getting x11 to start on ereader already running a Linux Distro independently on sdcard

Tags: bash, kernel, x11

I burn a customized recovery image onto a sdcard that gives me ssh and adb access over wifi. I mount the sdcard and successfully get into the Linux Distro image.

I enter these commands over adb on the device and x11 will not show up. I've already installed the drivers into the linux distro.

> startx -- tty01 -sharevts -novtswitch
>
> while true; do echo 1 > /sys/class/graphics/fb0/epd_refresh; sleep 2;
>   done & xterm

It throws error saying display is not set. I try to set display with `set DISPLAY: 0` or `set DISPLAY: 1` or `set DISPLAY :tty01`

Doesn't work.

> root@localhost:~# startx
>
> Fatal server error: Can't read lock file /tmp/.X0-lock
>
> Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support      at
>   http://wiki.x.org  for help.   ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
>
> giving up. xinit:  Stale NFS file handle (errno 116):  unable to
>   connect to X server xinit:  No such process (errno 3):  Server error.

Here are some links of instructions that I followed.

[X running on nook touch(independent without stock os)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2298141)

[simple touch tweaked to run linux distros](https://hackaday.io/project/163769-nook-simple-touch-tweaked-to-run-linux-distros)

**UPDATE**

Some information has been deleted as it was no longer needed and the problem has been fixed, but startx is still being difficult to launch.

I have managed to get one step closer by running **fsck.ext2 -fyc /sdcard/ubuntu.img**  while running the aforementioned startx command these errors popped up.

What should I do now with this information?

**Here, I try to find the device files for the screen. I look into graphics and fb0 is beyond my knowledge.**  (NOTE THIS IS THE ANDROID's DEVICE DIRECTORY)

The first screenshot of the ubuntu's /dev folder and the 2nd is android's
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried with `ssh -X`?

Comment: I had issues with it and I believe that maybe it won't start because fsck can't run on a .img file.

Comment: I've runned fsck.ext2 /sdcard/ubuntu.img and /usr/bin/X: error while loading shared libraries: libpciaccess.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to run `fsck.ext2`, which is a text mode program. It needs no X, but should write its output in the text screen or terminal window, where it was started. - There could be a problem with the image: 1. If it is an **image of the partition** with an ext file system, it should work, but 2. if it is an image of the whole drive, it could be difficult to point to the partition, so that `fsck.ext2` will find the file system. Maybe you can use `kpartx` for that purpose. - What was the result of `fsck.ext2`?

Comment: Libraries are destroyed. Going to have to recopy image. :(

Comment: Trial and error. I messed around with ldconfig and it fixed some problems, but anway  forget about it lets go back to what work in step 1!(Just started working on copying after trying to fix broken system)

Comment: Have to go to bed its 307 am.

Comment: Okay, I'm back. Startx is no longer showing errors about shared libraries or stale nfs. But now, trying to figure out the display needed to be set.